# Access rights to shared memory

Tags: linux, shared-memory

I've got 2 applications communicating via shared memory.

Process 1 creates the shared memory in `/dev/shm` with permissions of 600

However, process 2 can't access the memory although it runs under the same user. Changing the permissions to 666 solves it.

But why? 2 processes from the same user should be able to access it, or am I getting something wrong here?